# Collapsing ToolBar Layout always Colapse if Show PopUp Menu item RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml

I implement Collapsing ToolBar Layout in my Activity. I create RecyclerView too in this Activity. I Have problem, When I how PopUp Menu item RecyclerView, Collapsing ToolBar always Colapse.

This my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ad.kostrad.mp.activity.GambarLokasiActvity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <include
                layout="@layout/header_item_lokasi" />

          <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_gambar_lokasi_actvity" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So how to fix it ?

Comment: try adding this  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" in toolbar

Comment: yes i have set this... but stil not work

Answer (score 12):

Using

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v, Gravity.RIGHT);
```

does not help if you tap items close to the bottom of the screen. It will still try to perform a scroll up to fit the menu.

Actually there seems to be a bug in the support libraries. For a complete fix you can replace for now:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
```

with

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
```

as suggested for a similar question. The popupmenu will work as expected.

Comment: Replacing the import actually worked for me, thanks. Is there a bug report for this? If not, I think we should create it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this fix. I had no idea what would be causing this problem

Answer (score 5):

I Solve this with replace :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
```

to

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v, Gravity.RIGHT);
```